# How can I add 1D numpy array to the first column of a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add 1D numpy array to 2D numpy array?

For example:

```
Array1: 0  0
        0  0
        0  0

Array2: 1,2,3

Result: 1  0
        2, 0
        3, 0
```

How can I do it in python?

Comment: Your example and question are not well defined.. do you mean just to add the first column to a 1d array?

Comment: Yes, I just want to add first column.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((3,2))
y = np.array([1,2,3])

x[:, 0] += y
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this as a vector operation, instead of in a loop:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[0, 0], [0,0],[0,0]]) 
array2 = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Note that the first element of the transpose of array1 is the column vector you'd like to add array2 to:

```
array1.T[0]                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[10]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

So we can:

```
array1.T[0] = array1.T[0] + array2                                                                                                                                                                   
array1                                                                                                                                                                                               

Out[12]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0]])
```